# parsing utctime with aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

I can't get aeson to parse an UTCTime value. I tried to encode one and feed it back, but that didn't work:

```
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Time.Clock> getCurrentTime >>= (print . encode)
"\"2013-10-17T09:42:49.007Z\""
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Time.Clock> decode "2013-10-17T09:42:49.007Z" :: Maybe UTCTime
Nothing
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Time.Clock> decode "\"2013-10-17T09:42:49.007Z\"" :: Maybe UTCTime
Nothing
```

The FromJSON instance of the UTCTime type is the following ([ref](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.6.1.0/docs/src/Data-Aeson-Types-Class.html)):

```
instance FromJSON UTCTime where
    parseJSON = withText "UTCTime" $ \t ->
        case parseTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ" (unpack t) of
          Just d -> pure d
          _      -> fail "could not parse ISO-8601 date"
```

following the format description found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.0.2/docs/Data-Time-Format.html), everything should be ok. What am I missing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Prelude Data.Aeson Data.Time> decode (encode [x]) :: Maybe [UTCTime]
Just [2013-10-17 10:06:59.542 UTC]
```

Note the "pitfalls" section in the haddocks:

> Note that the JSON standard requires that the top-level value be
>   either an array or an object. If you try to use decode with a result
>   type that is not represented in JSON as an array or object, your code
>   will typecheck, but it will always "fail" at runtime:

...

> So stick to objects (e.g. maps in Haskell) or arrays (lists or vectors in Haskell):

Comment: I had read this section. However, my brain did not make the connection. Thanks!

Comment: One practical trick for getting around this is to just wrap your types in a list layer: `decode "..." :: FromJSON a => Maybe [a]`. I use this all the time for quickchecking subparsers. It's *much* easier than trying to rewire the inner Aeson parsers to get you nonstandard JSON behavior.

Comment: If you use the `value` parser from `Data.Aeson.Parser` you can override the spec. requirement of only parsing top-level json object / arrays, and parse individual values. Use it with attoparsec.