# Yesod Persistent using Aeson to parse UTCTime into record

Tags: yesod, aeson

I have my model from `models.persistentmodels`

```
...

Thing
    title Text
    price Int 
    kosher Bool
    optionalstuff [Text] Maybe
    createdat UTCTime
    updatedat UTCTime
    deriving Show

...
```

It contains two time fields, which are `UTCTime`.

I am receiving via AJAX what is *almost* a `Thing`, in JSON. But the user JSON should not have `createdat` and `updatedat` or `kosher`. So we need to fill them in.

```
postNewEventR = do
    inputjson <- requireCheckJsonBody :: Handler Value
...
    -- get rawstringofthings from inputjson
...

    let objectsMissingSomeFields = case (decode (BL.fromStrict $ TE.encodeUtf8 rawstringofthings) :: Maybe [Object]) of
                        Nothing -> error "Failed to get a list of raw objects."
                        Just x  -> x

    now <- liftIO getCurrentTime

    -- Solution needs to go here:
    let objectsWithAllFields = objectsMissingSomeFields

    -- We hope to be done
    let things = case (eitherDecode $ encode objectsWithAllFields) :: Either String [Thing] of
                        Left err -> error $ "Failed to get things because: " <> err
                        Right xs  -> xs
```

The error "Failed to get things" comes here because the JSON objects we parsed are missing fields that are needed in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

```
let objectsWithAllFields = Import.map (tackOnNeccessaryThingFields now True) objectsMissingSomeFields
```

So we take the current object and tack on the missing fields e.g. `kosher` and `createdat`.

But there is some strange difference in the way UTCTime is `read` vs [aeson's way to parse UTCTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19423533/parsing-utctime-with-aeson). So when I print UTCTime in to a Aeson `String`, I needed to print out the UTCTime into the format that it is expecting later:

```
tackOnNeccessaryThingFields :: UTCTime -> Bool -> Object -> Object
tackOnNeccessaryThingFields t b hm = G.fromList $ (G.toList hm) <> [
                                                                              ("createdat", String (pack $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ" t)),
                                                                              ("updatedat", String (pack $ formatTime defaultTimeLocale "%FT%T%QZ" t)),
                                                                              ("kosher", Bool b)
                                                                 ]

tackOnNeccessaryThingFields _ _ _ = error "This isn't an object."
```

After this fix, the object has all the fields needed to make the record, so the code gives `[Thing]`. 
And also the code runs without runtime error, instead of failing to parse the `tshow t` as UTCTime.

Note:
This aeson github issue about this problem seems to be closed but it seems to be not any more permissive: https://github.com/bos/aeson/issues/197

Thanks to Artyom:
https://artyom.me/aeson#records-and-json-generics

Thanks to Pbrisbin:
https://pbrisbin.com/posts/writing_json_apis_with_yesod/

Thanks to Snoyman:
For everything